# Reopen question after release of 20.04

Tags: discussion, support

my question has been closed as addressing a not released version, but now it's released.

Please reopen.

[How to install Ubuntu 20.04 Focal Fossa remotely with virt-instlall?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228734/how-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-remotely-with-virt-instlall)

Comment: This question is now reopened.